# Validate date format in php

Tags: php, regex, date, validation

I'm trying to validate date using PHP.

I'd like following formats to be valid:

```
d/m/yy
d/m/yyyy
dd/m/yy
dd/m/yyyy
d/mm/yy
d/mm/yyyy
dd/mm/yy
dd/mm/yyyy
```

I've tried many regular expressions and different variations of checkdate() function. Currently I have something like this:

```
function _date_is_valid($str)
{
     if(strlen($str) == 0)
         return TRUE;
     if(substr_count($str,'/') == 2)
     {
         if (preg_match("/^((((31\/(0?[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)\/(0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])))\/(1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})|(29\/0?2\/(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))/", $str))
         {
             $datearray = explode('/',$str);
             if($datearray[2] > 2030)
                 return FALSE;
             return checkdate($datearray[1], $datearray[0], $datearray[2]);
         } 
         else 
         {
             return FALSE;
         }
     }
     return FALSE;
}
```

This however, validates dates like 11/11/200 and 11/11/200#

How can I validate date to match required format?

Edit: I could check datearray[2] to be between 10 and 30 and 2010 and 2030. But is there a way to check it using regex?

Edit1: return TRUE on strlen($str) == 0 is because I want users to be able to add events without knowing when will the event occur so someone else can qualify the schedule and assign event to certain date later

---

Just for the record. I ended up doing:

```
function _date_is_valid($str)
{
    if(strlen($str) == 0) //To accept entries without a date
        return TRUE;
    if(substr_count($str,'/') == 2)
    {
        list($d,$m,$y) = explode('/',$str);
        if(($y >= 10 && $y <= 30) || ($y >= 2010 && $y <= 2030))
        {
            return checkdate($m,$d,$y);
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Thanks for all your answers

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
function _date_is_valid($str) {
    if (substr_count($str, '/') == 2) {
        list($d, $m, $y) = explode('/', $str);
        return checkdate($m, $d, sprintf('%04u', $y));
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Should be checkdate(), not check_date(). Other than that, looks good to me. +1

Comment: if you don't check the count of '/' it will throw a php notice or warning on invalid strings

Comment: I modified this a bit to not validate dates after certain year as php checkdate() validates years like 20111 which in this case is not what I want

Comment: What if there are no two separating `/`?

Answer (score 8):

If it will always will be date / month / year you can use [`checkdate`](https://www.php.net/checkdate):

```
function _date_is_valid($str)
{
    $array = explode('/', $str);

    $day = $array[0];
    $month = $array[1];
    $year = $array[2];

    $isDateValid = checkdate($month, $day, $year);
    return $isDateValid;
}
```

Comment: Should be checkdate(), not check_date(). And you might want do a isset() for the $array indices. Other than that, looks good to me. +1

Comment: oh yes, you are right, it is checkdate(), copied from the question without checking it. Thanks

Comment: What if there are no two separating `/`?

Answer (score 3):

an easy way to do this

```
<?php
    if(!$formated_date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d',$dateVar))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function _date_is_valid($str) {
    if (strlen($str) == 0) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return preg_match('/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/((?:\d{2}){1,2})$/', $str, $match) && checkdate($match[2], $match[1], $match[3]) && $match[2] <= 2030;
}
```

Comment: I want to allow date to be left empty or in valid format. It's sort of event calendar where you can book an event for a certain date or book an event and someone else will allocate the date to it later

Comment: Doesn't check the day or month are valid.

Comment: @Douglas Leeder: `checkdate` checks for valid dates.

Comment: Sorry - didn't notice the horizontal scroll. And the preg_match fit on the displayed width.

Answer (score 1):

I have been just changing the martin answer above, which will validate any type of date and return in the format you like.

Just change the format by editing below line of script strftime("10-10-2012", strtotime($dt));

```
<?php

        echo is_date("13/04/10");

        function is_date( $str )
        {
        $flag = strpos($str, '/');

        if(intval($flag)<=0){
          $stamp = strtotime( $str );
         }else {
          list($d, $m, $y) = explode('/', $str);      
          $stamp = strtotime("$d-$m-$y");
         } 
          //var_dump($stamp) ;

          if (!is_numeric($stamp))
          {
             //echo "ho" ;
             return "not a date" ;       
          }

          $month = date( 'n', $stamp ); // use n to get date in correct format
          $day   = date( 'd', $stamp );
          $year  = date( 'Y', $stamp );

          if (checkdate($month, $day, $year))
          {
             $dt = "$year-$month-$day" ;
             return strftime("%d-%b-%Y", strtotime($dt));
             //return TRUE;
          }else {
          return "not a date" ;
          }
         }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did to validate it was simple

```
    function dateValidate($pDate) {
    if(empty($pDate)) 
        return true; 
    $chDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($pDate));
    if($chDate != '1970-01-01')
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

You can find it out with using regexp too

Answer (score 0):

how about `if(strtotime($str) !== FALSE) $valid = TRUE;`

Comment: -1: OP was very specific about what formats to accept. Your solution allows for many more formats.

Comment: and also there's an issue between dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy